# F# Method overload resolution not as smart as C#?

Tags: f#

Say, I have

```
member this.Test (x: 'a) = printfn "generic"
                           1
member this.Test (x: Object) = printfn "non generic"
                               2
```

If I call it in C#

```
var a = test.Test(3);         // calls generic version
var b = test.Test((object)3); // calls non generic version
var c = test.Test<object>(3); // calls generic version
```

However, in F#

```
let d = test.Test(3);  // calls non generic version
let e = test.Test<int>(3); // calls generic version
```

So I have to add type annotation so as to get the correct overloaded method. Is this true? If so, then why F# doesn't automatically resolve correctly given that the argument type is already inferred? (what is the order of F#'s overload resolution anyway? always favor `Object` than its inherited classes?)

It is a bit dangerous if a method has both overloads, one of them takes argument as `Object` type  and the other one is generic and both return the same type. (like in this example, or `Assert.AreEqual` in unit testing), as then it is very much likely we get the wrong overloading without even notice (won't be any compiler error). Wouldn't it be a problem?

Update:

Could someone explain

- Why F# resolves `Assert.AreEqual(3, 5)` as `Assert.AreEqual(Object a, Object b)` but not `Assert.AreEqual<T>(T a, T b)`
- But F# resolves `Array.BinarySearch([|2;3|], 2)` as `BinarySearch<T>(T[]array, T value)` but not `BinarySearch(Array array, Object value)`

Comment: You seem to be missing a question mark.. somewhere.

Comment: @ildjarn Ok I will add a few

Comment: Have you tried `test.Test<_>(3)`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> F# Method overload resolution not as smart as C#?

*I don't think it's true. Method overloading makes type inference much more difficult. F# has reasonable trade-offs to make method overloading usable and type inference as powerful as it should be.*

When you pass a value to a function/method, F# compiler automatically upcasts it to an appropriate type. This is handy in many situations but also confusing sometimes.

In your example, `3` is upcasted to `obj` type. Both methods are applicable but the *simpler* (non-generic) method is chosen.

[Section 14.4 Method Application Resolution](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc335819028) in the spec specifies overloading rules quite clearly:

> 1)     Prefer candidates whose use does not constrain the use of a
>   user-introduced generic type annotation to be equal to another type.
>
> 2)     Prefer candidates that do not use ParamArray conversion. If two
>   candidates both use ParamArray conversion with types pty1 and pty2,
>   and pty1 feasibly subsumes pty2, prefer the second; that is, use the
>   candidate that has the more precise type.
>
> 3)     Prefer candidates that do not have
>   ImplicitlyReturnedFormalArgs.
>
> 4)     Prefer candidates that do not have
>   ImplicitlySuppliedFormalArgs.
>
> 5)     If two candidates have unnamed actual argument types ty11...ty1n and ty21...ty2n, and each ty1i either
>
> a.     feasibly subsumes ty2i, or
>
> b.     ty2i is a System.Func type and ty1i is some other delegate
>   type, then prefer the second candidate. That is, prefer any candidate that has the more specific actual argument types, and
>   consider any System.Func type to be more specific than any other
>   delegate type.
>
> 6)     Prefer candidates that are not extension members over
>   candidates that are.
>
> 7)     To choose between two extension members, prefer the one that
>   results from the most recent use of open.
>
> 8)     Prefer candidates that are not generic over candidates that are
>   generic—that is, prefer candidates that have empty ActualArgTypes.

I think it's users' responsibility to create unambiguous overloaded methods. You can always look at inferred types to see whether you're doing them correctly. For example, a modified version of yours without ambiguity:

```
type T() =
    member this.Test (x: 'a) = printfn "generic"; 1
    member this.Test (x: System.ValueType) = printfn "non-generic"; 2

let t = T()
let d = t.Test(3)  // calls non-generic version
let e = t.Test(test) // call generic version
```

**UPDATE:**

It comes down a core concept, [**covariance**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29). F# doesn't support covariance on arrays, lists, functions, etc. It's generally a good thing to ensure type safety (see [this example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29#Arrays_in_C.23_and_Java)).

So it's easy to explain why `Array.BinarySearch([|2;3|], 2)` is resolved to `BinarySearch<T>(T[] array, T value)`. Here is another example on function arguments where

```
T.Test((fun () -> 2), 2)
```

is resolved to

```
T.Test(f: unit -> 'a, v: 'a)
```

but not to

```
T.Test(f: unit -> obj, v: obj)
```

Comment: There are quite a few BCL .Net methods that are ambiguously overloaded (they resolve fine in C#). I had thought F# resolution is the same as C# for consistency in dealing with .Net methods..

Comment: Method overloading makes type inference much more difficult. Considering that F# is a functional programming language, I think the language has made reasonable (pragmatic) choices.

Comment: Could you plz help look at my updated question, why does F# resolution favor differently in `Assert.AreEqual` and `Array.BinarySearch`?